# Razor Pages - Relationship One-To-Many

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-relationship, razor-pages

I am trying to present a one-to-many relationship and errors always appear and I cannot move forward.
If anyone can identify the errors, thank you very much.
The final objective is to choose a record in the Villas table and to be able to associate records in another table.
Thanks

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace LeisureVillas.RazorPages.Models
{
    public class VillaStatAContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<StatementA> Tbl_Statement_Autos { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Villa> Tbl_Villas { get; set; }
        public VillaStatAContext(DbContextOptions<VillaStatAContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }
        #region Required
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
           modelBuilder.Entity<Villa>()
               .HasMany<StatementA>(s => s.StatementAs)
               .WithOne(p => p.Villas)
               .HasForeignKey(s => s.Stat_A_Villas);
            #endregion
        }
    }
}

using LeisureVillas.RazorPages.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace LeisureVillas.RazorPages.Pages
{
    [Authorize(Roles = "Manager")]
    public class VillaStatementA : PageModel
    {
        private readonly VillaStatAContext db = null;

        public List<Villa> Villas { get; set; }
        public List<StatementA> StatementAs { get; set; }

        public void OnGet()
        {
            this.Villas = (from e in db.Tbl_Villas orderby e.Vill_Name select e).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: at this moment it presents an error, because I set db = null and I can't go from here

Comment: And I intend to take the relationship of the two tables to the cshtml page

Comment: It won't be null if you do : `db = new VillaStatAContext()`

Comment: You probably want to use dependency injection to supply the `VillaStatAContext` as a page model constructor.

Comment: error CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'options' of 'VillaStatAContext.VillaStatAContext(DbContextOptions<VillaStatAContext>)'

Comment: OK, yes, you need to supply the db options because there is no parameterless constructor. It would be best to configure it for dependency injection as Jeremy mentioned.

Comment: This is the same relationship I have in SQL:  Foreign Key Base Table: Tbl_Statement_Auto <br/> Foreign Key Coumns: Stat_A_Villas <br/> Primary/Unique Key Base Table: Tbl_Villas <br/> Primary Key Columns_ Vill_ID

Comment: was showing an error and changed the line below:
         public void OnGet ()
         {
             this.Villas = (from e in _db.Tbl_Villas orderby e.Vill_Name select e) .ToList ();
         }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use denpendency injection metioned in comment:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Manager")]
public class VillaStatementA : PageModel
{
    private readonly VillaStatAContext _db;

    public VillaStatementA(VillaStatAContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public List<Villa> Villas { get; set; }
    public List<StatementA> StatementAs { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        this.Villas = (from e in db.Tbl_Villas orderby e.Vill_Name select e).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: At the moment there is no longer any error in the code, but the html is not opening. It displays the following error: "Unexpected error while processing this request."

Comment: Swap to the Development environment  to display detailed information.

Answer (score 0):

```
@page
@model VillaStatementA
<h3>Suppliers Automatic</h3>
<div class="flex-cont">
    <div class="flex-item-left">
        <font size="2" face="Courier New">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th style="display:none;" bgcolor="#5D7B9D"><font color="#fff">ID</font></th>
                    <th bgcolor="#5D7B9D"><font color="#fff">Code</font></th>
                    <th bgcolor="#5D7B9D"><font color="#fff">Customer Name</font></th>
                    <th bgcolor="#5D7B9D"><font color="#fff">Address</font></th>
                    <th bgcolor="#5D7B9D"><font color="#fff">Location</font></th>
                </tr>
                @foreach (var item in Model.Villas)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td style="display:none;">@item.Vill_ID </td>
                        <td>@item.Vill_Code</td>
                        <td>@item.Vill_Name</td>
                        <td>@item.Vill_Address</td>
                        <td>@item.Vill_Location</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </table>
        </font>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item-right">2</div>
    <font size="2" face="Courier New">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th style="display:none;" bgcolor="#5D7B9D"><font color="#fff">ID</font></th>
                <th bgcolor="#5D7B9D"><font color="#fff">Villa</font></th>
                <th bgcolor="#5D7B9D"><font color="#fff">Amount Débit</font></th>
               <th bgcolor="#5D7B9D"><font color="#fff">Memo</font></th>
            </tr>
            @foreach (var item in Model.StatementAs)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td style="display:none;">@item.Stat_A_Id</td>
                    <td>@item.Stat_A_Villas</td>
                    <td>@item.Stat_A_Amount_Debt</td>
                    <td>@item.Stat_A_Memo</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    </font>
</div>
```

Comment: At the moment there is no longer any error in the code, but the html is not opening. It displays the following error:
"Unexpected error while processing this request."

Comment: You should debug to find the error details.

Comment: I can't see anything anymore !! In 6 hours I have to get up to go to work. I really appreciate your help.